# Programmatically disable network auto-tune in Windows Vista

Tags: networking, windows-vista

One of our applications is exhibiting poor network behavior on Vista due to the new network stack's auto-tuning functionality.  I'm working on tracking down why the problem's happening, but in the meantime, it'd be wonderful if we could simply disable auto-tuning on our application for the time being.  Is there any way to do so programmatically, ideally just on a per-application basis?  The only solution I've found is to use an elevated command-prompt—not an acceptable solution for our users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [SO_RCVBUF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526885.aspx) socket option on your applications TCP socket. This should override the auto-tuned receive window with the value you supply ([see](http://smallvoid.com/article/vista-tcpip-auto-rwin.html)).